# How to detect if the surface keyboard is attached?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, winjs, windows-rt

I need to implement certain functions only when the keyboard is attached to the surface. Is there a way I can detect when the surface keyboard is attached or removed ?

I tried this code on Surface:

```
function getKeyboardCapabilities()
{   
   var keyboardCapabilities = new Windows.Devices.Input.KeyboardCapabilities();
   console.log(keyboardCapabilities.keyboardPresent);

}
```

The result was always '1' even when the keyboard was not connected.

Comment: My understanding is that you can know whether one has been attached, but not whether it currently is attached. Look at `KeyboardCapabilities.KeyboardPresent`

Comment: @WiredPrairie I tried using `KeyboardCapabilities.keyboardPresent` on a computer with a physical keyboard and the result was '1' which is good. However the same code on a Surface always returned '1' even when the keyboard was not attached.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that's just how it works. Surface always reports true if it's been attached at some point.

Comment: Have any magical solutions appeared in the last 4 years?

Answer (score 2):

I used this code to identify when a keyboard is connected to a Surface:

```
var keyboardWatcher = (function () {
    // private
    var keyboardState = false;

    var watcher = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.createWatcher();
    watcher.addEventListener("added", function (devUpdate) {
    // GUID_DEVINTERFACE_KEYBOARD
        if ((devUpdate.id.indexOf('{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}') != -1) && (devUpdate.id.indexOf('MSHW0007') == -1)    ) {
            if (devUpdate.properties['System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled'] == true) {
                // keyboard is connected 
                keyboardState = true;
            }
        }
    });
    watcher.addEventListener("updated", function (devUpdate) {

        if (devUpdate.id.indexOf('{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}') != -1) {
            if (devUpdate.properties['System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled']) {
                // keyboard is connected 
                keyboardState = true;
            }
            else {
                // keyboard disconnected
                keyboardState = false;
            }
        }
    });

    watcher.start();

    // public
    return {
        isAttached: function () {
            return keyboardState;
        }
    }

})();
```

Then call `KeyboardWatcher.isAttached()` whenever you need to check the status of the keyboard.

Comment: Tried this solution on the surface pro and unfortunately when the OnScreenKeyboard pops up it sets the flag to `true`

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a good way to detect if a keyboard is attached so instead I detect if I am in tablet mode or desktop mode.

```
        bool bIsDesktop = false;

        var uiMode = UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode;
        if (uiMode == Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UserInteractionMode.Mouse)          // Typical of Desktop
            bIsDesktop = true;
```

Note the other possible value of uiMode is Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UserInteractionMode.Touch.

Comment: For a surface pro with no keyboard attached this returns true, so this solution doesnt work in this case